# Assigning value to a parameter passed to an extern C function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, extern

I have 2 functions in 2 different projects:

P1.cpp has the function:

```
void assignParam()
{
   int x= 0;
   changeValue(x);
   //value of x is still 0
}
```

P2.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int changeValue(int x = 0)
{   x = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

How to make x get value 5? How to retain values assigned to parameters in extern c functions

Comment: Pass a pointer or reference to `x` maybe?

Comment: It's a default parameter

Comment: This function doesn't change the caller's value, only its own parameter copy. It would need to take a reference or a pointer. (I'm not sure whether an `extern "C"`function can take a reference, since C doesn't support that. Anybody?)

Comment: @PeterSchneider They can, though the implementation of the function must (of course) also be done in C++.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: There's nothing to forbid an `extern "C"` function taking a reference. How that would interact with a C program is "implementation-defined and language-dependent".

Comment: What will not work with `extern "C"` is the default argument.

Comment: @sjdowling: No, that's fine. It just won't be usable from C.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for the answer. Then arises the question: Let's have the following scenario: a C program which calls a function implemented in C++ which is declared `"extern C"` and takes a reference. Would that link? Would the function alter the caller's argument?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: That would be "implementation-defined and language-dependent". You'd have to refer to the ABI used by your C and C++ compilers. I can't imagine that it could modify the argument in a C program. Perhaps it will work if the C program declares the function to take a pointer; perhaps it won't work at all.